# Inline Form: Control width of inputs?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, youtube

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and I'm basically trying to recreate Youtube's share form under the videos where you copy the code and have the option to checkbox what time you want to start the video at. But the inputs aren't staying on the same line instead the second input is stacked under the first and both take up 100% of the width. The checkbox and text sandwiched in between. I want to set the second input to about 20% and the first input would just be responsive to fit the rest of the space. Any ideas? Thanks in advance for any help.

http://jsfiddle.net/6Kr7r/

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="url" class="form-control" id="user_input" value="" placeholder="Youtube link here..."/>

        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value=""/> Start at:
          </label>
        </div>

        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="seconds" value="" placeholder="0:00"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried and CSS or are you asking for the CSS?

Comment: @DutGRIFF I've tried using CSS, I set each input width to 50%, but they still are on separate lines. I also tried putting the code in a row and setting each input with a class of "col-md-x" and that wasn't working either. So yeah, asking for the CSS if anyone has a solution.

Comment: Well I have them all on one line here: http://jsfiddle.net/6Kr7r/2/. Is that what you want? You can't set them both to 50% because that won't leave room for the checkbox and label.

Comment: @DutGRIFF that is what it should look like but it's not working in my case for some reason. I'm guessing it needs to be a Bootstrap solution instead of quick styling.